# detect hovering on chart point - google visualization line charts

Tags: google-visualization, mouseleave

I'm using the google visualization line-charts, and I'm using the following events to detect when a point on the chart is hovered or not.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (rowColumn) {
            alert("mouseOver");
        });
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseleave', function (rowColumn) {
                alert("mouseLeave");
            });
```

the first one works perfectly, but the second does nothing!
How can I enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function (rowColumn) {
    alert("onmouseout");
});
```